# c# datetime utc string and the z when using in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I am getting a date from my api and the format i get is `"2019-04-17T15:04:28"`
the date is UTC.
Should the date i get back have the Z at the end or doesn't it matter. Javascript date function will display incorrect if the Z is not there wont it?

Thanks @Esko thanks i think for me the confusion is that in .net core if you change the json serializer options in `startup.cs` by the following:

```
AddJsonOptions(opt =>{ 
  opt.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
            });
```

the tool tip in visual studio says [image] yet it doesn't put the Z on and the documentation also doesn't show the Z (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateFormatHandling.htm)

Instead i am going to try and set a different option

```
opt.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
```

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do with this date.

Comment: If it's your api, why doesn't it return the Z if the date is infact UTC? If the api is not done by you, and you are certain the times are UTC, just append the Z after fetching if needed. Don't now exactly what is your question beyond that.

Comment: i will be using a third party grid to display rows of data. It takes a date object and displays the date and time in local time

Comment: the api is from another team member and they are using json.net serializer - it doesn't add the z

Comment: @JimmyShoe You can control how json.net serializes dates. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateTimeZoneHandling.htm

Comment: Same problem here, I don't see any reasonable answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the timezone to be constant, you can always just append +0Z00 to your datestring. For example, if the server serializes time into CEST, turn `"2019-04-17T15:04:28"` into `"2019-04-17T15:04:28+0100"`

Parsing `"2019-04-17T15:04:28"` in new Date will parse it as if it's in your local timezone - the meaning of this string depends on what timezone it's parsed in.

Parsing `"2019-04-17T15:04:28Z"` will parse it in GMT - meaning that no matter what system parses it, it will always refer to the same time.

In other words, `"2019-04-17T15:04:28"` as a timestamp is ambiguous unless you know the timezone it was recorded in.

Comment: @cheziHoyzer would you mind expanding on why? What drawbacks do you expect Adding 'Z' to bring in this case?

Comment: You need to try fix problems related to server in the server side (And I did fix it like my answer below) and not add workarounds in the client...

Comment: @cheziHoyzer If you can change the api, you're definitely right. I assumed it's a 3rd party api or something we've got no control over. If it is, what would you rather do?

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem and I found the answer
In my case the DateTime was with `Kind` `Unspecified`, in this case the JsonConvert hasn't enough information to add the Z in the end.

You have several options:

1. Convert it to UTC with [ToUniversalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=netcore-3.1) method
2. If you're sure you're working with UTC you can add it to general JsonOptions like this:

```cs
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = (() =>
{
    return new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() 
        {
            new IsoDateTimeConverter 
            { 
                DateTimeStyles = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal 
            }
        }
    };
});
```

3. if you just want to add the Kind=UTC to current Unspecified Date, you can always write isoConverter like this:

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter>() {  new CustomIsoDateTimeConverter() }
};
```

Where the class will look like this:

```cs
public class CustomIsoDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime dateTime && dateTime.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
            value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        base.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);
    }
}
```